# Handling KeyPress with Embedded Macros

Tags: ms-access, event-handling, ms-access-2010

In VBA, I can handle `KeyPress` with a subroutine. But my workplace has disabled VBA macros. I have been able to create most event handlers for my forms with Access’s embedded macros using the macro builder, but I have not figured out how to handle certain events where the event handler has arguments in VBA.

The `KeyPress` event has the argument `KeyAscii` in VBA. But I do not know how to get that value in an embedded macro. I’ve tried `[LocalVars]![KeyAscii]`, but apparently, that does not exist.

Is it possible to handle `KeyPress` with embedded macros? And if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, sorry, that's just plain impossible.

While you can do many things without VBA, this is a situation that does require it.

Embedded macros don't support any of the parameters normally passed to event handlers.